# Two plots within one facet in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, facet-wrap

I have two types of data to create two types of plot, bar and line. They have different y axis, but same x axis. They are each categorized by the same category levels

Example Code:

```
data <- data.frame( Station = sample(LETTERS[seq( from = 1, to = 4 )],50, rep = TRUE),
                  Date = sample(seq(as.Date('2015/01/01'), as.Date('2015/12/31'), by="day"), 50),
                   Presence = sample(0:10,50,rep = TRUE),
                   Noise = sample(70:130,50, rep=TRUE))
noise <-  ggplot()+
    geom_line(data = data,aes(x=Date, y= Noise, color= Station))+
    scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month")+
    facet_wrap(~Station, ncol=2, strip.position="right")+
    theme(axis.title.x = element_text(margin = margin(t = 20)))+
    guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=3)))+
    coord_cartesian(xlim = c(as.Date("2015-02-01"),as.Date("2015-10-30")))+
    labs( x='Date')+
    theme_classic(base_family = "serif")
```

[image]

```
pres <-ggplot()+
  geom_bar(data = data,aes(x= Date, y = Presence), stat = "identity")+
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month")+
  facet_wrap(~Station, ncol=2, strip.position="right")+
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(margin = margin(t = 20)))+
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(as.Date("2015-02-01"),as.Date("2015-10-30")))+
  labs( x='Date')+
  theme_classic(base_family = "serif")
```

[image]

What I would like to do, is to combine the two plots, but label with the same facet (Station).

Quick example I made in photoshop would look something like this:

[image]

etc.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: check the ggh4x package - it allows for nested facets

Comment: r2evans - okay I can try and figure that out - I don't used stackoverflow often, not really sure how it all works

Comment: tjebo, the nested facets look like the right idea, but how to get the two plots in the same figure to be faceted is what I'm now stuck on

Answer (score 1):

`ggplot` doesn't have a pretty way of doing this but it can certainly be done:

```
ggplot()+
  geom_line(data = data,aes(x=Date, y= Noise, color= Station))+
  geom_bar(data = data,aes(x= Date, y = Presence*10), stat = "identity")+
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month")+
  scale_y_continuous(
    name = "Noise",
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~./10, name="Presence")
  ) +
  facet_wrap(~Station, ncol=2, strip.position="right")+
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(margin = margin(t = 20)))+
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=3)))+
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(as.Date("2015-02-01"),as.Date("2015-10-30")))+
  labs( x='Date')+
  theme_classic(base_family = "serif")
```

So what is done here is adding the `geom_bar` after the `geom_line` and adding `scale_y_continuous`. The `sec.axis` in the latter provides a second axis *however* all the plots will be drawn on the primary axis regardless, the secondary axis has no functionality. In order to make proper use of it we need to define the scale bewteen the axes ourselves and add them to `geom_bar` and `sec.axis`.

The result looks as follows:
[image]

You can also use the package `ggbreak` to create a break in the y-axis while both plots remain on the same y-axis like so:

```
ggplot()+
  geom_line(data = data,aes(x=Date, y= Noise, color= Station))+
  geom_bar(data = data,aes(x= Date, y = Presence), stat = "identity")+
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month")+
  scale_y_break(breaks = c(10, 70), scales = 1.5)+
  facet_wrap(~Station, ncol=4, strip.position="right")+
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(margin = margin(t = 20)))+
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=3)))+
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(as.Date("2015-02-01"),as.Date("2015-10-30")))+
  labs( x='Date')+
  theme_classic(base_family = "serif")
```

Which will look like so:
[image]

I unfortunately wasn't able to make this work for `ncol=2` as the order of the plots will mess up.

Comment: I had done something like this with the two plots together, but my supervisor prefers them to be on separate y-axes

Comment: What functionality of having a second y-axis are you missing in this answer?

Comment: likely readability - my true data overlaps each other in a single graph, and so having two separate graphs means being able to look at the changes in y at a finer scale

And also altering the scale of either one of the datas would give errors in the results

Comment: @GabrielleMacklin added a solution to my original answer. I don't think a lot more is possible within the `ggplot2` package

Comment: @Wieste de Vries I'll wiggle with it a bit, but unfortunately with the overlapping data it doesn't break nicely (the bar plot goes up to 100, the line plot goes down to 70)

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to just create 8 plots in that case?

Comment: very possibly - I just feel that the double title (as there are two graphs per station) makes it less readable. And they are somewhat connected, so I was hoping to find a way to connect them. But it might not be possible.